# Cómo agrupar resultados de una consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¡Hola!
Tengo un problema a la hora de agrupar los resultados de una consulta a la base de datos, he probado varias cosas, pero no sé qué me falta... Os enseño una imagen para explicarme mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, me salen varias filas del pedido 1, del 2... y lo que quiero es que bajo cada fila verde con el número de pedido, salgan los detalles de ese pedido. He probado con GROUP BY, pero así lo único que consigo es que me salga solo una línea por cada pedido (cuando tienen más):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Copio el código, a ver qué me falta (o qué me sobra). Como veis, los campos son de dos tablas distintas:

```
<?php 
$sql_pedidos = "SELECT DISTINCT (b.npedido), b.nmatricula, b.estado, a.isbn, a.titulo, a.edicion, a.curso, a.nivel, a.editorial, a.serie, a.idioma
FROM libros AS a
INNER JOIN pedidos AS b ON b.isbn=a.isbn
ORDER BY b.npedido";

$resultset = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_pedidos) or die("error base de datos:". mysqli_error($conexion));

while($pedidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) 
{
?>
<thead>
 <tr id="<?php echo $pedidos['npedido']; ?>">
   <th colspan="1" class="tcabecera">Pedido nº: <?php echo $pedidos['npedido']; ?></th>
   <th colspan="3" class="tcabecera">Matrícula: <?php echo $pedidos['nmatricula']; ?></th>   
   <th colspan="1" class="tcabecera">Estado: </th>
   <th colspan="3" class="tcabecera"><?php echo $pedidos['estado']; ?></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['isbn']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['titulo']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['edicion']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['curso']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['nivel']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['editorial']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['serie']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $pedidos['idioma']; ?></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
<?php
 } 
?>                           
</table>
```

He probado también a hacer dos tablas por separado, pero al hacerlo así se me complica porque quiero editar dinámicamente el campo de estado y, aunque he probado con el atributo contenedittable de html5 no he sido capaz de conseguirlo, así que prefiero hacerlo todo de una.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat), entiendo que se agrupa por número de pedido y matrícula.

```
SELECT
    pedido,
    matricula,
    GROUP_CONCAT(isbn) AS isbns,
    GROUP_CONCAT(titulo) AS titulos,
    GROUP_CONCAT(edicion) AS ediciones,
    GROUP_CONCAT(curso) AS cursos,
    GROUP_CONCAT(nivel) AS niveles,
    GROUP_CONCAT(editorial) AS editoriales,
    GROUP_CONCAT(serie) AS series,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('', IFNULL(serie, ' '))) AS serie_con_nulls
    GROUP_CONCAT(idioma) AS idiomas
FROM
    tabla
GROUP BY pedido, matricula;
```

Posteriormente en el while, la cabecera igual que la tienes, y hacer dentro otro bucle, para recorrer el array generado por [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) del group_concat de la consuta.

```
//Misma cabecera 

$ar_isbns = explode($pedidos['isbns'],',');
$ar_titulos = explode($pedidos['titulos'], ',');
.....

/*Otro bucle, la longitud de estos arrays es la misma*/

for($i=0;$i<count($ar_isbns);$i++){
  //Generar las filas con $ar_isbns[0], $ar_isbns[1], ....
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo del [group_concat](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c19c2/9) donde hay valores null, donde devolveremos un espacio en blanco, separados por comas.

Comment: Muchsímas gracias, Vicent, pero he dejado una respuesta a mi pregunta porque me queda clara la parte del for ;)

Comment: Ups! en el comentario anterior quería decir que NO me queda clara, jeje. Aprovecho para comentar también que viendo los errores (aparte de que solo me salen las comas del explode), de la última imagen que he adjuntado, las líneas que señala se corresponden al campo serie, que no todos los libros tienen, es decir, en algunos libros ese campo está como NULL, pero no sé cómo solucionar el error de "vacío" que aparece. Millones de gracias, de nuevo.

Comment: Añado a la respuesta teniendo en cuenta que puede haber nulls para el group_concat

Comment: Mejor modifica la pregunta inicial, no hace falta que respondas con otra entrada.

Comment: Perdona la tardanza en contestarte, Vicent. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Muchísimas gracias, Vicent. Aunque no me queda muy clara la parte del for dentro del while... He hecho una pruba, pero claramente está mal, porque da error

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Copio lo que he modificado del código, así será más fácil que me indiques  lo que me falta :)

```
<?php 
$sql_pedidos = "SELECT b.npedido, b.nmatricula, b.estado, GROUP_CONCAT(a.isbn) AS isbns, GROUP_CONCAT(a.titulo) AS titulos, GROUP_CONCAT(a.edicion) AS ediciones, 
GROUP_CONCAT(a.curso) AS cursos, GROUP_CONCAT(a.nivel) AS niveles, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(a.editorial) AS editoriales, GROUP_CONCAT(a.serie) AS series, 
GROUP_CONCAT(a.idioma) AS idiomas
FROM libros AS a
INNER JOIN pedidos AS b ON b.isbn=a.isbn
GROUP BY b.npedido, b.nmatricula
ORDER BY b.npedido";

$resultset = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_pedidos) or die("error base de datos:". mysqli_error($conexion));

while($pedidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) 
{
 $isbns = explode($pedidos['isbns'],',');
 $titulos = explode($pedidos['titulos'], ',');
 $ediciones = explode($pedidos['ediciones'], ',');
 $cursos = explode($pedidos['cursos'], ',');
 $niveles = explode($pedidos['niveles'], ',');
 $editoriales = explode($pedidos['editoriales'], ',');
 $series = explode($pedidos['series'], ',');
 $idiomas = explode($pedidos['idiomas'], ',');
?>
 <thead>
  <tr id="<?php echo $pedidos['npedido']; ?>">
   <th colspan="1" class="tcabecera">Pedido nº: <?php echo $pedidos['npedido']; ?> 
   </th>
   <th colspan="3" class="tcabecera">Matrícula: <?php echo $pedidos['nmatricula']; ? 
   ></th>   
   <th colspan="1" class="tcabecera">Estado: </th>
   <th colspan="3" class="tcabecera"><?php echo $pedidos['estado']; ?></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
   <th class="tcabecera"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php
 for($i=0;$i<count($isbns);$i++)
 {
?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $isbns[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $titulos[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $ediciones[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $cursos[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $niveles[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $editoriales[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $series[$i]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $idiomas[$i]; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</tbody>
<?php
} 
?>
´´´
PD. Creo que esto debería ir como comentario, pero no podía escribir todo por falta de espacio ;)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtEf9.png
```

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, para que puedas ver como hacer el group_concat con valores nulos y en lugar de no devolver el valor devuelva la cadena vacía. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c19c2/9